# Padding text with content of grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using grid layout in CSS and I have a span, with a grid on the bottom.
Each cell of my grid have a centered content and i would like to add padding on left and right to my text for being align with the content of cell in both side.
I would like a full css solution, but i'm not sure if it's possible...

```
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</span>
<div class="grid-container grid-container--fill">
  <div class="grid-element">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-element">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Here is a jsfiddle if u want to try some stuff :
https://jsfiddle.net/s4Lxwrm5/

Comment: are there always 4 elements in the grid or is it dynamic?

Comment: There is no property that would allow this at present (I suspect `display:subgrid` would be required). You may need to rethink your layout method.

Comment: @kukkuz dynamic .. :(

Comment: Am I really going to get negative votes on my correct answer?

Answer (score -2):

Here you go buddy:

```css
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 overflow: auto;

 background-color: grey;
}
 .container-inner {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1248px; /* SET YOUR MAX WIDTH */
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px; /* SET YOUR PADDING */
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;

  background-color: orange;
 }
  .text-container {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
   padding-left: calc((100% / 4) / 10); /* WORK OUT THE WIDTH OF ONE GRID BOX BY DIVIDING BY THE NUMBER OF BOXES YOU ARE 'gridding'. THEN DIVIDING BY 10 WILL GIVE YOU THE 10% PADDING THAT I SPECIFY LATER ON IN THE CSS */
   padding-right: calc((100% / 4) / 10); /* WORK OUT THE WIDTH OF ONE GRID BOX BY DIVIDING BY THE NUMBER OF BOXES YOU ARE 'gridding'. THEN DIVIDING BY 10 WILL GIVE YOU THE 10% PADDING THAT I SPECIFY LATER ON IN THE CSS */
   position: relative;
   text-align: justify;

   background-color: red;
  }
  .supporting-boxes {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 25%);

   background-color: green;
  }
   .grid-box {
    width: 80%; /* LEAVING 10% PADDING */
    height: auto;
    min-height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    justify-self: center;

    background-color: purple;
   }
    .box-content {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     text-align: center;

     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

     background-color: pink;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="container-inner">
  <div class="text-container">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div class="supporting-boxes">
   <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="box-content">
     A
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="box-content">
     B
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="box-content">
     C
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-box">
    <div class="box-content">
     D
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is quite volatile code though, if you're changing the number of boxes and stuff we may need to look for another solution.

Comment: Why are there all these divs? How do I actually extract the principles behind your answer? A reader should not have to put substantial amount of time to understand an answer, or to extract meaning from it. The indentation is messed up, there is white space everywhere, at a glance it's impossible to tell what you are doing. It seems that you expect OP to simply copy paste and leave it at that. This is not what Stack Overflow is about, we want to create content that is valuable for many people.

Comment: Sure - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp will explain how to use divs, I have also commented on the most relevant CSS, that helps center the text to the width of the inner content that is in the grid (answering the question). The indentation wasn't messed up I simply had spaced it out. If copied and pasted without editing it, they will just have the result you see when it is run, they will have to remove all the background colors, insert their own copy or template it however they decide. Either way I have used generic naming structure and given them a correct answer with annotations.

Comment: Apart from the condescension, you've really not answered my points. This answer is unsuitable to help other humans. Nothing in it can teach how to solve a particular problem. Why does it need a maximum width. Why can't it be dynamic. What if op needs more than four divs? This is the kind of things you should explain in your answer, for it to become a quality answer.

Comment: What are you on about, you... He wants to know if it is possible... YES. I have proved that. While explaining in the css what is necessary to change if there is a different number of boxes and explained the math. There is no requirement to have a max-width - just remove it and you have a full width element. To be fair buddy if you're struggling to read through that basic CSS and HTML you probably shouldn't be going around auditing other peoples answers. Refer to the docs like everyone else. I am using basic principles, that people with basic knowledge will know. I can't explain every line.